# Laravel validate each file separately

Tags: php, laravel, validation, file-upload

I would like to validate size of multiple files, and if size does not fit , i want to resize that single file, if size fit i upload it in original size.

I have a few inputs on front:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <strong>SELECT MAIN IMAGE (required)</strong>
     <input type="file" name="files[fileMain]" id="fileMain" class="form-control-file border 
      mb-1 {{ $errors->has('fileMain') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" >
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="form-group">
     <input type="file" name="files[]" id="file1" class="form-control-file border mb-1 
     {{$errors->has('file') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" >
</div>
```

in my controller :
i use :

```
foreach($request->file('files') as $index => $file) {
   // Laravel validators methods works only for arrays so new Request array is created here
   $single_file_array = new Request(
    [
       'files[]' => $file
    ]);
    // send single file to validator
    $imageSizeValidation = ImageUtil::imageSizeValidator($single_file_array, 
    ENUMS::MAX_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_FOR_PROVIDER);

    if($imageSizeValidation) {
       $new_name = ImageUtil::uploadOriginalImageFileToBlogFolder2($file, $dest_folder);
    } else {
        // resize image and save to dB
        $new_name = ImageUtil::resizeImage2($file, ENUMS::MAX_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_FOR_PROVIDER, 
        $dest_folder);
    }
}
```

and my validator looks like :

```
$sizeValidator = Validator::make($request->all(),
   [
      'files.*' => Rule::dimensions()->maxWidth($predefined_max_size)
   ]);

   if($sizeValidator->fails()) {
      return false;
   }
   
   return true;
```

all files are true :( it means validator does not see files and dont validate them.
What is wrong with this code ?
How can I validate single file and after , decide what to do if fails that single file
I dont want to send all files at once because it will not let me decide about single file.

Answer (score 1):

Well i figure out solution like below.
I take each file (from $request->files() and made a new Request containing that file (new instance of UploadedFile) and validate that  new request.
I think it is more workaround that real solution but no one sugested anything better.
My code :

```
foreach($request->file('files') as $index => $file) {
   $single_file_request = new Request();

   $uploadedFileAddress = $file->getPathname();
   $new_file = new UploadedFile($uploadedFileAddress, "files[$index]"); 
   $single_file_request->files->set("files", ['files' => $new_file]); 

   $imageSizeValidation = ImageUtil::imageSizeValidator($single_file_request, ENUMS::MAX_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_FOR_PROVIDER);

// rest of the code 
}
```

It's not perfect but do a job.
And now after validation of each file I can decide what to do with it :)
Maybe this will inspire someone to figure out other/better solution :)